# Using Arduino GSM library to switch on IComSat GSM board

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs

I program my IComSat board attached to an Arduino Uno. It works, but the Icomsat module needs to be switched on by hand and I want to do that in software.

I using GSM_GPRS_IDE100_v309.zip

I using:

```
digitalWrite(GSM_ON, HIGH);
delay(300); /* spec says 200 should suffice */
digitalWrite(GSM_ON, LOW);
```

which is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look in the GSM.h file. By default GSM_ON is defined as pin 8 and GSM_RESET is at pin 9, but for the IComSat that is different:

```
#define GSM_ON       9 
#define GSM_RESET    8
```

You can see that on the schematics ( http://www.komputer.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sch-icomsat-v1.1.pdf ) page 2: PERKEY and D9 are connected, RESET and D8

Comment: That worked. The GSM_Shield2.zip downloaded from there had the same problem!